# Having trouble loading an image instead of using a drawn object in actionscript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am trying to make a ball shoot from a canon, which is fine, but i want to change the canon from a drawn canon into an image i have OF a canon.
But when i do this i get the following error when i click on the stage to shoot the balls while with the drawn version the balls shoot as planned:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at code2/createNewBullet()
>       at code2/mouseClickHandler()

**This is the code that works:**

```
private function init():void {

        drawBoard = new MovieClip;
        drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0); // white transparant
        drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(drawBoard);
        // create canon
        canon = new MovieClip;
        canon = new MovieClip;
        canon.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        canon.graphics.drawRect(0, -10, 50, 20);
        canon.graphics.endFill();
        canon.rotation = -45;
        canon.x = 25;
        canon.y = gameHeight;
        addChild(canon);
```

**This is what i am trying to do to use an image instead of a drawn rectangle for the cannon** 
((The image loads fine but causes the error))

```
private function init():void {
        // create drawboard (the important movieclip, that holds all visible elements)
        drawBoard = new MovieClip;
        drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0); // white transparant
        drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(drawBoard);

        var canon:Loader = new Loader();
        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("cannon1.png");
        canon.load(fileRequest);
        canon.rotation = -45;
        canon.x = 25;
        canon.y = gameHeight;
        addChild(canon);


    }
```

**And this is the full code if needed:**

```
package {

// Copyright 2010-2011 - Seinia.com
// Find more crazy good AS3.0 tutorials and games on Seinia.com!

// imports
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;

// Game class (MovieClip extension)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class code2 extends MovieClip {

    // game properties
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var drawBoard:MovieClip;
    var background:MovieClip;
    var gameWidth:int = 600;
    var gameHeight:int = 300;
    var gravity:Number = .4;
    var bullets:Array;
    var canon:MovieClip;

    // constructor
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function code2():void {
        this.focusRect = false;
        this.init();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler, false, 0, true);
        bullets = new Array();
    }

    // init the game
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private function init():void {
        // create drawboard (the important movieclip, that holds all visible elements)
        drawBoard = new MovieClip;
        drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0); // white transparant
        drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(drawBoard);

        var canon:Loader = new Loader();
        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("cannon1.png");
        canon.load(fileRequest);
        canon.rotation = -45;
        canon.x = 25;
        canon.y = gameHeight;
        addChild(canon);


    }

    // mouse click handler
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        createNewBullet();
    }

    // function to create a new bullet
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private function createNewBullet():void {
        // init and draw bullet
        var bullet:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
        bullet.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        bullet.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
        bullet.graphics.endFill();
        // define bullet start point and speed
        var cos:Number = Math.cos(canon.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        var sin:Number = Math.sin(canon.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        var speed:Number = 8;
        bullet.x = canon.x + cos * canon.width;
        bullet.y = canon.y + sin * canon.width;
        bullet.vx = cos * speed;
        bullet.vy = sin * speed;
        bullets.push(bullet);
        addChild(bullet);
    }

    // enter frame handler
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
        for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ ) {
            // gravity
            bullets[i].vy += gravity;
            // move bullet
            bullets[i].x += bullets[i].vx;
            bullets[i].y += bullets[i].vy;
            // remove star from stage?
            if (bullets[i].y >= gameHeight) {
                removeChild(bullets[i]);
                bullets.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
var canon:MovieClip;
```

is defined as a private variable and is available inside all class methods, where as

```
var canon:Loader = new Loader();
```

you define in init function is available only in this function scope. After function ends, all variables defined in functions scope are discarded. 
Also note that first and second variable are two different variables.

To fix your problem you should make class variable to a Loader
and during init function create loader and assign the value to it. This way it will be available in all functions in this class, like such

```
package {

// Copyright 2010-2011 - Seinia.com
// Find more crazy good AS3.0 tutorials and games on Seinia.com!

// imports
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;

// Game class (MovieClip extension)
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --
public class code2 extends MovieClip {

    // game properties
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    var drawBoard:MovieClip;
        var background:MovieClip;
    var gameWidth:int = 600;
    var gameHeight:int = 300;
    var gravity:Number = .4;
    var bullets:Array;
    var canon:Loader;

    // constructor
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    public function code2():void {
        this.focusRect = false;
        this.init();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler, false, 0, true);
        bullets = new Array();
    }

    // init the game
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    private function init():void {
        // create drawboard (the important movieclip, that holds all visible elements)
        drawBoard = new MovieClip;
        drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0); // white transparant
        drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(drawBoard);

        canon = new Loader();
        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("cannon1.png");
        canon.load(fileRequest);
        canon.rotation = -45;
        canon.x = 25;
        canon.y = gameHeight;
        addChild(canon);


    }

    // mouse click handler
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    private function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        createNewBullet();
    }

    // function to create a new bullet
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    private function createNewBullet():void {
        // init and draw bullet
        var bullet:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
        bullet.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        bullet.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
        bullet.graphics.endFill();
        // define bullet start point and speed
        var cos:Number = Math.cos(canon.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        var sin:Number = Math.sin(canon.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        var speed:Number = 8;
        bullet.x = canon.x + cos * canon.width;
        bullet.y = canon.y + sin * canon.width;
        bullet.vx = cos * speed;
        bullet.vy = sin * speed;
        bullets.push(bullet);
        addChild(bullet);
    }

    // enter frame handler
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
        for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ ) {
            // gravity
                bullets[i].vy += gravity;
            // move bullet
            bullets[i].x += bullets[i].vx;
            bullets[i].y += bullets[i].vy;
            // remove star from stage?
            if (bullets[i].y >= gameHeight) {
                removeChild(bullets[i]);
                bullets.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`canon` has no scope in your `createNewBullet()` method.

You need to declare `canon` as a class member variable.

Currently canon is a local variable to the `init()` method.

As pointed out by the commenter, you do need to change the canon to a Loader type in your declarations.

Comment: I was just typing a similar answer. He actually declares a `cannon` variable that is a `MovieClip` at the top of the class. He needs to change that declaration to a `Loader` instead (and then use the member variable and not instantiate a new local variable w/the `var keyword`).

Comment: yeah, I didn't notice that in the full code, till you mentioned it. But  he also cannot use `var canon:Loader = new Loader();` in his `init()` method or the variable will be local and still result in an error.